# angular formly read-only mode for radio , multiCheckbox and checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I need to display the form in read-only mode , I am creating the form based on Json using angular-formly . Checked the link http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/read-only-form which works for text input , please suggest how to set read-only for radio , multicheckbox and checkbox

Comment: set ng-readonly property to true
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly

Comment: I am creating the form using angular-formly , can't set ng-readonly for angular-formly

Comment: can you please make a plunker for it, so i can fix it for you

Answer (score 1):

we do it via jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

OR if you want to "pretend" you are using "angular" to do this, even though you are actually using jQuery, and want to type out a whole lot more code to write the exact same thing(literally, it will simply run the above code in jQuery as angular.element is an "alias" for jQuery---straight out of the angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), you can do:

```
   angular.element(function() {
        angular.element('input').trigger('click')(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        };
   });
```

This way you can look cool and spout off nonsense like "It's bad practice to run angular and jQuery together" because you have no clue what you are talking about and just read that somewhere.

This works for all input fields.  If you have buttons or datepickers with buttons, etc the easiest way to do it is to set a readOnly property on the model in the form and then set it to true on page where you want it to be read only then set the ng-show on the buttons to: `ng-show="!model.readOnly"`

Comment: Using jQuery with Angular is a bad practice. Avoid it as long as you can

Comment: Why? Angular uses jquery inherently...oh sorry, you want me to "pretend" to use angular by calling angular.element even though angular.element is angular's implementation of jquery(either jquery Lite if you don't have it installed or maps directly to jQuery if it is installed).  It's only "bad practice" because someone said it was without even understanding what is going on under the hood.  Straight off the angular docs:  "angular.element is an alias for jquery."  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element.  Anyone saying not to mix angular and jquery is clueless